# 'Fill caps' not working in Geometry of Mesh Curve

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, geometry, bevel

I tried to make a coral but was unable to fill the caps. As you can see, the option is not clickable. I also can't see options like 'Round', 'Object', or 'Profile' and I don't understand why.

I made this shape by making a UV sphere, extruding hair, and converting it to a curve, then making the spline type Bezier and Automatic handle type. Then I added depth in Geometry > Bezel but I am unable to fill in the caps.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The version that you are using is a bit outdated, [grab the latest version](https://www.blender.org/download/) to get fill caps [without bevel object](https://archive.blender.org/developer/D8911):

[image]